# Remove last text block in a text

Tags: python, replace

I want to remove `home.php` from following text:

```
loc='C:/xampp/htdocs/dump/home.php'
```

I don't think I can use `loc.replace('home.php', '')` since the actual text after the final `/` may change (for example, `update.php`).

How do I remove the final section regardless of what it contains? For example:

```
c:/xampp/htdocs/dump/home.php -> c:/xampp/htdocs/dump/
/somedir/somefile             -> /somedir/
```

Comment: Re "Without using ..", why? Without an explanation, this is just an artificial constraint, worthy of the same disdain as "I need to sort something in C but can't use `qsort()` for some reason I deign not to share". If the restriction is something like "`home.php` may be different text", *specify* that. Otherwise `replace()` or `loc[:-8]` are perfectly valid solutions.

Comment: If we had a different text other than "home.php", how do we identify last text block and remove that last block.

loc1='C:/xampp/htdocs/dump/index.php'
loc2='C:/xampp/htdocs/dump/home.php'
loc3='C:/xampp/htdocs/dump/update.php'

So I want to get only,
loc='C:/xampp/htdocs/dump/'

Comment: Mohan, that's better, though it really should be added to the question. I'll give it a shot ... see if that better explains what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
loc = "C:/xampp/htdocs/dump/home.php"
index = loc.rindex("/")
loc = loc[:index+1]
print(loc)
```

Comment: We can't use home.php. If we have another name like update.php or login.php, how do I remove the final section ???

Comment: Well then you should just say you want to remove the file name and keep the path..

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
import os
loc = os.path.dirname(loc)
```

Read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the many solutions to your question. Hope this helps.

```
loc = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/dump/home.php'
loc_new  = loc.rstrip('home.php')

# This will be the result of this.
>> C:/xampp/htdocs/dump/
```

Comment: We can't use home.php. If we have another name like update.php or login.php, how do I remove the final section ???

Comment: To remove only the file name and keep the path - `os.path.dirname(loc)` is the right way to do it, as mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Separate the path and then join the parts you want

```
 loc='C:/xampp/htdocs/dump/home.php'
 "/".join(loc.split("/")[:4]) + "/"
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for the general case;

```
loc = "/somedir/somefile" 
loc = '/'.join(loc.split('/')[:-2]) + '/'
```